# Technical name for text between XML tags

Tags: xml

```
<fizzBuzz>
    Some text
</fizzBuzz>
```

What's the technical name (using XML verbage) for the text between `fizzBuzz`'s starting and ending tags (in this case, `Some text`)? I am whipping up some documentation and almost referred to this as `CDATA`, but then stopped myself. And then I realized, to my horror, that I had no idea what it was.

Content? Tag bodies?

Online searching turned up, to my great surprise, nodda. Maybe this post can put an end to that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply called the [content](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-content) of the [element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-element).

Comment: No, that also includes elements inside an element.

Comment: @bmargulies: "Some text" is character data physically, but content semantically; I guess there are two questions that can be answered here.

Comment: Yea, I'm assuming he's talking about the plain chars, as opposed to the embedded elements. If it's both, it's PCData, no?

Answer (score 3):

From the XML Specifications document:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-physical-struct

> [Definition: An XML document may consist of one or many storage units.
>   These are called **entities**; they all have **content** and are all (except
>   for the document entity and the external DTD subset) identified by
>   entity name.]

Comment: So is it an entity or content?

Comment: "<fizzBuzz>Some text</fizzBuzz>" is the entity. "Some text" is the content.

Comment: That is from the physical construct.  From the same specification: `Each XML document has both a logical and a physical structure. Physically, the document is composed of units called entities. An entity may refer to other entities to cause their inclusion in the document. A document begins in a "root" or document entity. Logically, the document is composed of declarations, elements, comments, character references, and processing instructions, all of which are indicated in the document by explicit markup.`  So the logical composition answer would be ELEMENTS and CONTENT.

Answer (score 2):

Character data. See [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCDATA)

Answer (score 0):

"Content" is the correct term.